# Canvas ctx.drawimage() not working

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, drawimage

I am trying to render some pictures into a canvas, but when I use my rendering function, the images won't appear. The function is:

```
function populateSquareImages(){
    for(var i = 0,ii = squares.length; i < ii; i++) {
        if(squares[i].hasImage) {
            var img = new Image();
            img.src = "../Content/Squares/images/square_" + squares[i].uniqueId + ".png";
            context.drawImage(img, squares[i].x, squares[i].y);
        }
    }
}
```

After some debugging, I am sure that x and y are accurate. The image file path is correct as well. Any idea of what might be wrong here?

Comment: **Use image.onload:** `var img=new Image; img.onload=function(){context.drawImage(img,0,0);}; img.src='something.png';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait for the image to load before attempting to draw it. This should work:

```
function populateSquareImages () {
    for (var i = 0, ii = squares.length; i < ii; i++) {
        if (squares[i].hasImage) {
            var img = new Image(),
                square = squares[i];
            img.src = "../Content/Squares/images/square_" + squares[i].uniqueId + ".png";
            img.onload = function () {
                context.drawImage(img, square.x, square.y);
            };
        }
    }
}
```

The variable `i` will not be correct inside the callback function by the time it gets called, so store the value of `squares[i]` in another variable called `square`.